# Ionic: Loose vertical scrollbars when injecting views into a splitview

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been playing with the split view, and started looking at the routing. I wanted to set up a "main layout" splitview, and then use the routing to inject various views into it at runtime, as in this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vEZqJEnP4deEeDrTQHYM).

So, in the layout view (layout.html), I have

```
<ion-side-menus>
<ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
       <h1 style="text-align: left" class="title">Main</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content >
        <!-- Inject Main view here -->
        <ion-nav-view name='main'></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-content>

</ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu width=200 expose-aside-when='(min-width:300px)'>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal">
        <h1 style="text-align: left" class="title">Options</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <!-- Inject Side options vew here -->
      <ion-nav-view name='options'></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

The routes are setup in script.js...

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
 .state('view1', {
   url: '/',
   views: {
      'main': {
       templateUrl: 'mainv1.html'
     },
     'options': {
        templateUrl: 'optionsv1.html'
     },      
   }
   });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
   });
```

The views seem to get in there fine, but I seem to loose the scrollbars in the splitview (see the righthand view where I have added 100 `<div>` elements.

Anyone know if there is a way to do the above and have the vertical scroll working?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a [`ion-scroll`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/) directive in your **mainv1.html**:

```
<div ng-controller='main'>
  <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="height: 100%;">
    <div ng-repeat='d in data'>{{d}}</div>
  </ion-scroll>
</div>
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pfVSgJpYFBeRMYwMRvru?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for that, seems to work fine (as long as native scrolling, not js scrolling is enabled). Also to hide the I added the `<ion-content scroll=false>`. Strange that we need to use another scroll container, rather than use the `ion-content` scrolling, and gets a little weird if I was to enable js scrolling, ie `$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(true);` as shown [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/BslrGstF41m24l7MBrh0). Other than that, seems to be a working solution/workaround.